# Convergence of the series $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n/(\sqrt[n]{n})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Consider convergence of the following series.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[n]{n}}.$$

My try:

Set $u_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\to 1.$

Hence the series diverges.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct. The term of the series does not converge to $0$, hence the series diverges.